# insert values from various drop down list to database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP. I have no experience on Object oriented PHP. I have experience only in Raw PHP.

I am trying to inserted the value of my drop down box to the database. This is my code given here.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $roll=$_POST['roll'];
            $first_exam=$_POST['first_exam'];
            $second_exam=$_POST['second_exam'];
            $third_exam=$_POST['third_exam'];
            $fourth_exam=$_POST['fourth_exam'];
            $fifth_exam=$_POST['fifth_exam'];
            include 'db.php';

            $sql= "INSERT * INTO roll (id,Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th)
                            VALUES (NULL,$roll,$first_exam,$second_exam,$third_exam,$fourth_exam,$fifth_exam)" 
                                    or die (mysql_error());
            $result=  mysql_query($sql);
            if ($result){
                echo 'ok doen';

            }
            else {
                echo 'dont';
            }
        }

        ?>
    </body>



    <form method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>Roll:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="roll" /></td>
         </tr>
         <br></br>
    </form>


          <form method="post">      
          <?php echo "first_exam";?>
          <select name="first_exam">        
          <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
          <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
          <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
          <option  value="eng">English</option>
          <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
           </select>
       </form>
         <br></br>

      <form method="post">   
          <?php echo "second_exam";?> 
          <select name="second_exam">        
          <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
          <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
          <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
          <option  value="eng">English</option>
          <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
           </select>
       </form>
         <br></br>

         <form method="post">   
          <?php echo "third_exam";?> 
          <select name="third_exam">        
          <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
          <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
          <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
          <option  value="eng">English</option>
          <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
           </select>
       </form>
         <br></br>

         <form method="post">   
          <?php echo "fourth_exam";?> 
          <select name="fourth_exam">        
          <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="phy">Physics</option>
          <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
          <option  value="eng">English</option>
          <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
           </select>
       </form>

         <br></br>

         <form method="post" action="">   
          <?php echo "fifth_exam";?> 
          <select name="fifth_exam">        
          <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
          <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
          <option value="chem">Chemistry</option>
          <option value="eng">English</option>
          <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
           </select>
       </form>

         <br></br>
         <form method="post">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
         </form>
  <br><br>
</form>
</html>
```

I have gotten $_post['roll'],$_post['first_exam'] these error.

Comment: Each of your `select` is in a separate `<form>` tag; you need one form tag for everything.

Comment: See my edited answer. It will help you @shawon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a lot of mistakes in your code, here is a full working example:

HTMl & PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Divix Help</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $roll=$_POST['roll'];
        $first_exam=$_POST['first_exam'];
        $second_exam=$_POST['second_exam'];
        $third_exam=$_POST['third_exam'];
        $fourth_exam=$_POST['fourth_exam'];
        $fifth_exam=$_POST['fifth_exam'];
        include 'db.php';

        $sql= "
            INSERT INTO roll (id,Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th)
            VALUES (NULL,$roll,$first_exam,$second_exam,$third_exam,$fourth_exam,$fifth_exam)
        ";
        //echo $sql;
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($result){
            echo 'ok doen';
        } else {
            echo 'dont';
        }
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Roll:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="roll" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br></br>

        <?php echo "first_exam";?>
        <select name="first_exam">
            <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
            <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
            <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
            <option  value="eng">English</option>
            <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
        </select>
         <br></br>

        <?php echo "second_exam";?>
        <select name="second_exam">
            <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
            <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
            <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
            <option  value="eng">English</option>
            <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
        </select>
         <br></br>

        <?php echo "third_exam";?>
        <select name="third_exam">
            <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
            <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
            <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
            <option  value="eng">English</option>
            <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
        </select>
         <br></br>

        <?php echo "fourth_exam";?>
        <select name="fourth_exam">
            <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="phy">Physics</option>
            <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
            <option  value="eng">English</option>
            <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
        </select>
         <br></br>

        <?php echo "fifth_exam";?>
        <select name="fifth_exam">
            <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
            <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
            <option value="chem">Chemistry</option>
            <option value="eng">English</option>
            <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
        </select>

        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

- As mentioned by others you had too many `<form>` tags, remember that you only need 1 form tag in order to send multiple fields via `POST` or `GET` method.
- You had mistakes in SQL (do not put `INSERT * INTO`, **star** sign goes only into `SELECT` statements)
- Broken HTML structure, like missing `</body>`, `</html>` tags
- And last but not least `or die (mysql_error());` you put that against `execute` or `connect` function of mysql not against strings.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a simple mistake there. Instead you made many , just make one form & add all select into it...

Something like this:

`<form method="post">
code here
</form>`

Comment: That's problem solved. But now its shows "dont" and the table of my database is empty.. please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make 1 Form.

Change this too.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO roll (Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th) VALUES ($roll,$first_exam,$second_exam,$third_exam,$fourth_exam,$fifth_exam)";

$result=  mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

This is also one problem. Use `or die (mysql_error());` in mysql functions, not in statement.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Roll:</th>
            <th>First Exam</th>
            <th>Second Exam</th>
            <th>Third Exam</th>
            <th>Fourth Exam</th>
            <th>Fifth Exam</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="roll" /></td>
            <td>
                <select name="first_exam">        
                    <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="second_exam">        
                    <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="third_exam">        
                    <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="fourth_exam">        
                    <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="fifth_exam">        
                    <option  value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $roll=$_POST['roll'];
    $first_exam=$_POST['first_exam'];
    $second_exam=$_POST['second_exam'];
    $third_exam=$_POST['third_exam'];
    $fourth_exam=$_POST['fourth_exam'];
    $fifth_exam=$_POST['fifth_exam'];
    include 'db.php';

    $sql= "INSERT INTO roll (id,Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th) VALUES (NULL,$roll,$first_exam,$second_exam,$third_exam,$fourth_exam,$fifth_exam)";
    $result=  mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    if ($result){
        echo 'ok doen'; 
    }
    else {
        echo 'dont';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenhot**
[image]

Comment: thanks sir. But i'm confused. The type of data of $roll,$first_exam,$second_exam,$third_exam,$fourth_exam,$fifth_exam are int/varchar! I have completed the database using "varchar" type data for these variable. Please help me

Comment: @ShawonPaul  It's ok. Varchar is OK for All Exams. But, tell me one thing.. roll no is only digit or having alphabet ? And, one more thing, make your `column 'Id'` in `roll table` as `primary key` and `auto-incremented`.

Comment: roll no is only digit. And the ID in roll table is also as primary key and auto increment sir.

Comment: @ShawonPaul  Then, It's OK. Let all be varchar. No Problem. Run It. I've edited my answer again. Please copy paste whole code and run it. And, please let me know what happened next . Thanks.

Comment: Ok sir.. I am trying it.

Comment: Sir .. now its shows   "Unknown column 'math' in 'field list'  " and the table of my database is aslo empty

Comment: Ok. No problem. Don't take tension. everything is alright. Tell me. Your column name is like 1st, 2nd, 3rd.. ?? @ShawonPaul

Comment: what are your exact column name in `table roll` . tell me. @ShawonPaul

Comment: Sir they are id,Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th     .

Comment: See, i've edited my answer with screenshot of result. Data executing correct. You may have some problem with your database table structure. Check it. 
`echo "INSERT * INTO roll (Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th) VALUES ($roll,$first_exam,$second_exam,$third_exam,$fourth_exam,$fifth_exam)";`
comment after `include "db.php"; to else {echo 'don't'}`. and run the result in sql part of your database table. and, see the error there @ShawonPaul

Comment: Run this query `INSERT * INTO roll (Roll,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th) VALUES (123,phy,math,chem,eng,bio); ` in your sql of your database table @ShawonPaul

Comment: Sir I have inserted it. But it shows " #1054 - Unknown column 'phy' in 'field list'" error

Comment: I got error.. remove `*`  between `INSERT` & `INTO` It should be like ths way `INSERT INTO roll...` @ShawonPaul

Comment: Sir i have done that before. I analyzed a problem. If i selected firs exam as mathematics,then it shows an errr  "Unknown column 'math' in 'field list' " and further if i inserted physics in first exam. Then it shows "Unknown column 'phy' in 'field list'" error.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I have a small issue in the dropdown value, if i choose anyone all of my dropdown value inserted into my table. My report form : url -> paste.ofcode.org/UpeWjUWKNh5bHbfFKnAh9U  -> line between -> 365 to 367 & PHP dropdown source : url -> paste.ofcode.org/9Z3LNzzXNMA4ByAKbN6A8Q -> line start from 45

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I would like to point out.

1. Your *include* statements should always be at the top of your php document, it's a good programming practice.
2. Use *require_once* instead of *include* because it prevents the file from being included more than once in your php document.
3. Create and use a *Database* class to perform all your database operations.
4. Always sanitize your data using *real_escape_string* function before inserting to prevent SQL injection.
5. Always close your database connection at the end, it's a good programming practice.
6. And last but not the least, learn HTML and PHP properly.

Here's the complete code,

```
<?php 

// instead of include, use require_once
require_once('db.php'); 

// create and use Database class for all your database operations
class Database{
    public static function open_connection($host, $username, $password, $dbName){
        return new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbName);
    }

    public static function check_connection(){
        if(!mysqli_connect_error()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function execute_query($connection,$query){
        return $connection->query($query);
    }

    public static function close_connection($connection){
        $connection->close();
    }
}

?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $connection = Database::open_connection(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
    if(Database::check_connection()){
        // sanitize your input data
        $roll = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['roll']);
        $fifth_exam = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['first_exam']);
        $second_exam = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['second_exam']);
        $third_exam = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['third_exam']);
        $fourth_exam = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['fourth_exam']);
        $fifth_exam = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['fifth_exam']);

        // now insert into database
        // instead of taking id as NULL, take id as AUTO_INCREMENT 
        $query = "INSERT INTO table(roll_no, first_exam, second_exam, third_exam, fourth_exam, fifth_exam) VALUES ($roll, '$first_exam', '$second_exam', '$third_exam', '$fourth_exam', '$fifth_exam')";
        if(Database::execute_query($connection,$query)){
            echo "record is successfully inserted";
        }else{
            echo "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
    }else{
        echo "database connection failed";
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Roll No.</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="roll" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>First exam</td>
            <td>
                <select name="first_exam">        
                    <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Second exam</td>
            <td>
                <select name="second_exam">        
                    <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Third exam</td>
            <td>
                <select name="third_exam">        
                    <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Fourth exam</td>
            <td>
                <select name="fourth_exam">        
                    <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Fifth exam</td>
            <td>
                <select name="fifth_exam">        
                    <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                    <option  value="phy">Physics</option>
                    <option  value="chem">Chemistry</option>
                    <option  value="eng">English</option>
                    <option  value="bio">Biology</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// it's a good programming practice to always close database connection at the end
if(isset($connection)){
    Database::close_connection($connection);
}

?>
```

Comment: I have a small issue in the dropdown value, if i choose anyone all of my dropdown value inserted into my table. My report form : url -> paste.ofcode.org/UpeWjUWKNh5bHbfFKnAh9U  -> line between -> 365 to 367 & PHP dropdown source : url -> paste.ofcode.org/9Z3LNzzXNMA4ByAKbN6A8Q -> line start from 45

Comment: @Gem, Please formulate a new question and ask on SO.